# Basic Auth to authenticate webservice - PHP

Tags: php, soap, basic-authentication

I'm having a problem with authentication when I try to consume a web service soap. When entering with the url in the browser, it appears u dailog requesting user and password. But I need to do this authentication without this dialog being presented, that is, all authentication in the back end. I tried to pass the login and password through SoapHeader but without success. 
Note: the web-service is written in Java.
Here's the script:

```
 //!IMPORTANT: O tipo de autenticação é (Basic auth)    

 $credenciais = self::fncGeraAuth();   
 //array containing user and password for authentication   
 //Array ( [UserName] => xxxxx [Password] => xxxxx) 

 $_rCliente2 = new SoapClient($wsdl, array("encoding" => "ISO-8859-1"));  

 $Header = new SoapHeader($wsdl,'Authorization', $credenciais, false);

 $_rCliente2->__setSoapHeaders($Header);

 $result = $_rCliente2->fncRecuperaPapel($Instituição);

 var_dump($result);
 exit();
```

Error:

> SoapFault: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from '
>        ...........?wsdl' : failed to load external entity ".........wsdl"

I do not have much experience with webservice consumption and if someone can help me I appreciate it

Comment: That means the wsdl is not parsable (Is the url correct?)

Comment: I think not, because I tested on the post man and managed to get the return normally

Comment: Thanks guys for pointing me out a solution, i'm trying, but no success

Comment: Here is the actual script:

       $credentials = self::fncHash();
         $options = array(
           'UserName' => $credentials[Username],
           'Password' => $credentials[Password]
       );
    
        var_dump($options);
         echo "i'am here";
    
         $_rClient2 = new SoapClient($_uWS, $options);

         $result = $_rClient2->fncPaperRecovery($param);
    
         var_dump($result);
         echo "i'am here";